# C++: how do I convert an unsigned char to a string representing the binary value that the char has?

Tags: c++

```
char myChar = 0x01;
```

how do I get my output to be "00000001"

If there is a way to do it with a built in function, without a loop (I can do this with a loop, I just want to be elegant), that would be preferred ?

As for the why I'm doing this: I'm saving these numbers in a file that an external library needs this formatting (weird, I know, but libraries have rules).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use a [bitset](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/):

```
std::bitset<8> bits(myChar);
std::cout << bits << std::endl;
```

Comment: is there any reason (style, substance, or otherwise) to choose your form over the one-liner `std::cout << std::bitset<8>(myChar) << std::endl;`?

Comment: @Rob I wanted to make it explicit that `bitset` is a class, not a function. In real code I’d obviously use the temporary here.